# Which folders does IntelliJ add to the classpath for its different Run Configurations by default?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, classpath, settings

I have the following folder structure

```
src/
src/main/
src/test/
src/test/package/
src/test/package/FooTest.java
src/test/resources/
src/test/resources/foo/
src/test/resources/foo/a.txt
```

Here is FooTest:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(null != getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo/a.txt"));
    }

    public static void main (String... args) {
        System.out.println(null != FooTest.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo/a.txt"));
    }
}
```

When I run this as a JUnit test, I get `true` print out, when I run it as an Application, it's `false`.

The module setup looks like this:

[image: Module setup]

So, test/resources is not defined as a test resources folder.
Which is why I don't understand why I get `true` once and `false` the next time.

Could someone please explain how IntelliJ sets the classpath for the different Run Configurations (Application, JUnit test, Cucumber test) in general, and in particular why a.txt seems to be on the classpath for JUnit tests, even though it's not configured to be?

Answer (score 1):

If you "extract" the different method calls from within your `println` you will see a difference in the two approaches:

```
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        Class cls = getClass();         // cls is FooTest
        InputStream inputStream = cls.getResourceAsStream("foo/a.txt");
        System.out.println(null != inputStream);
    }

    public static void main (String... args) {
        Class cls1 = FooTest.class;     // cls1 is FooTest
        Class cls2 = cls1.getClass();   // cls2 is java.lang.Class
        InputStream inputStream = cls2.getResourceAsStream("foo/a.txt");
        System.out.println(null != inputStream);
    }
}
```

It is enough to use `FooTest.class` to get the relevant class.

`getResourceAsStream` is using the relative search path `foo/a.txt` relative to where `FooTest`

Comment: Thanks, @maba, that will probably solve my problem - but not really answer the question: why can the test find the text file when run from IntelliJ via the Run manu, when src/test/resources isn't on the classpath? (At least that's how I read the module setup above...) It's a maven project, and I'd expect maven to add that folder to the classpath, but I'm not running the test via maven...